# Visual Studio Express 2012 Crash on Startup (Windows 8.1 x64)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, windows-8.1

I am trying to use a copy of VS Express 2012 for school that I got off Dreamspark, and it crashes every time I start it up, even with the /safemode command on console. The crash is a simple blank window with the message: "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop has stopped working"

I tried reinstalling and restarting more than 3 times and I also tried to run VS Professional 2013 and it did the same crash. I also tried deleting some Registry keys while following step 2 of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246882 and it didn't fix the crashes.

I also tried this answer and it didn't help either: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12846564/4014679

I am in a bit of a loss here... and I need to have the software up and working before Monday for programming class. Can anyone help?

I also have the log available on PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/SnrJL1sF

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is an image showing the crash, the white that you see in the background is a fullscreen blank window, probably VS Express trying to open. http://i.gyazo.com/589c484338b2f1b477ecbd92a8b31567.png

Comment: Attach Windbg (from Windows 8.1 SDK) to it and run **!analyze -v**. Post to output please.

Comment: Since I cannot add more links to my main post... I'll add them here. Here's a pastebin of the Windbg output http://pastebin.com/CJcALSsw

Comment: I also have the crash info in the Windows Event Log if that helps https://www.dropbox.com/s/4g82buj6jg23igj/Crash%20Events.evtx?dl=0

Comment: you mistyped the command. It has a **Z** not a *S*. From the Eventlog I see that you get a **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException** at **MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.VerifyTextFormattingArguments**. Submit this to Microsoft at connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Comment: Alright, will submit to connect. Here's a corrected version of the Windbg Report (that the title is somehow still misspelled, but the command itself isn't ;P): http://pastebin.com/rW52hgfx

Comment: Tried to submit to connect, and the site is too bugged to actually do it.  They say I have to select a forum (which I did, numerous times) and they have to verify my account (no obvious way to do it). I tried with both Chrome and Firefox. Is my system that broken or is it Microsoft? Screenshot of the problems: http://i.gyazo.com/0faaf97c0fb36e457b9afebd5aeacc77.png

Comment: I have no idea why you can't submit it. It looks like try to post to the MSDN forums. Here is the link to create a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by disabling hardware acceleration via tools -> option -> Environment -> General menu.

check this post and specially the first answer for reference:
[enter link description here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7cedb4d-9907-45c1-8e8f-2ae8dea93f0d/visual-studio-2012-with-all-updates-crashes-consistently-under-windows-81-rtm?forum=w81previtpro)

It seems to be a problem of Intel graphic card.